# Android GC_CONCURRENT and soundbox app development

Tags: java, android

Firstly, sorry for my level in english.

I need some help. I'm trying to develop an app (a soundbox you click on a button and you hear a sound). I had no problem but after having had some songs, I have a memory problem. Here is my log :

```
enter code here11-10 15:21:02.446: E/Trace(942): error opening trace file: No such file         or directory (2)
11-10 15:21:03.535: D/dalvikvm(942): GC_CONCURRENT freed 83K, 2% free 8369K/8519K,         paused 83ms+4ms, total 149ms
11-10 15:21:03.535: D/dalvikvm(942): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 24ms
11-10 15:21:03.795: D/dalvikvm(942): GC_CONCURRENT freed 10K, 2% free 8813K/8903K, paused    74ms+17ms, total 134ms
11-10 15:21:04.026: I/Choreographer(942): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be    doing too much work on its main thread.
11-10 15:21:04.035: D/gralloc_goldfish(942): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-10 15:21:04.276: D/AndroidRuntime(942): Shutting down VM
11-10 15:21:04.276: W/dalvikvm(942): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40a13300)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting menu,   got TabHost
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:143)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at  android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at    com.example.famous.movies.sounds_.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:46)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix it ? I have put two tabs but the songs are just on the first one. Here is the code java :

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Gestion des onglets

        // Tout d'abord on récupère les ressources qui seront utilisés plus tard :
        Resources res = getResources();
        // On prépare les éléments nécessaires pour chaque onglet :
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;



        // on lie nos onglets à la principale activity :
        // ONGLET 1        
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Widget").setIndicator("Cinema", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.movies)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // ONGLET 2
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Form").setIndicator("Infos", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.infos)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // On choisit l'onglet par défaut
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}



public class Tab1 extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.onglet1);        

    final int sound11 = R.raw.carjacker;
    final int sound12 = R.raw.petitesoeur;
    final int sound13 = R.raw.cracherlama;
    final int sound14 = R.raw.maitresse;
    final int sound21 = R.raw.gandalfen;
    final int sound22 = R.raw.gandalf;
    final int sound23 = R.raw.gollum;
    final int sound24 = R.raw.gollumen;
    final int sound31 = R.raw.pasdebraspasdechocolat;
    final int sound32 = R.raw.sparta;
    final int sound33 = R.raw.sabre;
    final int sound34 = R.raw.darkvador;
    final int sound41 = R.raw.back;
    final int sound42 = R.raw.fightclub;
    final int sound43 = R.raw.forrestgump;
    final int sound44 = R.raw.iamyourfather;     
    final int sound51 = R.raw.loki;
    final int sound52 = R.raw.dinercon1;
    final int sound53 = R.raw.gollum;
    final int sound54 = R.raw.gollum; 
  /*  final int sound61 = R.raw.dinercondroit4;
    final int sound62 = R.raw.dinerconfemme5;
    final int sound63 = R.raw.dinerconchampion6;
    final int sound64 = R.raw.dinerconsonne7;  
   */
    generateSoundOnButton(sound11, R.id.btn11);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound12, R.id.btn12);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound13, R.id.btn13);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound14, R.id.btn14);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound21, R.id.btn21);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound22, R.id.btn22);        
    generateSoundOnButton(sound23, R.id.btn23);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound24, R.id.btn24);  
    generateSoundOnButton(sound31, R.id.btn31);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound32, R.id.btn32);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound33, R.id.btn33);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound34, R.id.btn34); 
    generateSoundOnButton(sound41, R.id.btn41);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound42, R.id.btn42);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound43, R.id.btn43);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound44, R.id.btn44);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound51, R.id.btn51);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound52, R.id.btn52);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound53, R.id.btn53);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound54, R.id.btn54);  
    /*
    generateSoundOnButton(sound61, R.id.btn61);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound62, R.id.btn62);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound63, R.id.btn63);
    generateSoundOnButton(sound64, R.id.btn64);  
   */
}


    public void generateSoundOnButton(final int soundId, int idButton) {

        final ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(idButton);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {       
                playSound(soundId);                 
            }

          });
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();          
        }
    }

    private void playSound(int resId) {     

        if(mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
        }
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

}



public class Tab2 extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onglet2);          
    }       
}
```

Actually at the beginning I removed the methode mPlayer.stop() because there were bugs and without this method it was working very well, so I thought it was now the problem but when I add again this method nothing happened, there are the same mistakes. Is there really a good way to play a sound correctly without problem on android ?

Any help and advice would be really appreciated. If you have any comments or questions, don't hesitate.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The error log showed that you have problem with menu. Are you running this on Android 4+ or lower?

Comment: The messages about memory are not an error, although they are clear in what might be happening - too much code on your UI thread.  The real error is here FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 15:21:04.315: E/AndroidRuntime(942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Expecting menu,   got TabHost

Comment: Yes my AVD manager is ICS 4.1 (with Eclipse), is it a problem ? And I create the app with android 2.1 in order that it works for all versions. How can I fix the error with the menu ? I recorded old stable version which where working perfectly and which are now not working...

Comment: You should check the method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`. The `R.layout.activity_main` is a layout and not a menu. In Android prior than 3.0 the method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` don't get called until you press menu button.

Comment: Actually the method getMenuInflater().inflate take an integer and a Menu so what is wrong ? I don't understand how I could fix this ...

Comment: Your xml file for the menu need to have `menu` as element root and the file need to be in `res/menu` folder. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Look to my second answer ;-)

Comment: Please read the doc carefully. If you have such a file you also need to refer as `R.menu.activity_main` and not `R.layout.activity_main`.

Comment: Ok it seems to fix the problem. Thank you very much for your help. However I don't understand why it was working at the beginning (I had several files since the beginning ...). I'll post here if I have any other problems. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes but it is already like it. I have an activity_main.xml in res/menu with this code :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" />
</menu>
```

And I have three files in res/layout : activity_main.xml with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- MISE EN PLACE DE LA BASE DE NOS 3 ONGLETS -->
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#66FF99">
    <LinearLayout  
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#E2F0FF">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
             />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#E2F0FF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And onglet1.xml equal tab1 with all songs (I think there are no others solution to write all the xml code ...?) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E2F2FF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
<!--  Ligne 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/petitesoeur" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/carjacker" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/cracherlama" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/maitresse" />
    </LinearLayout>

<!--  Ligne 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/gandalfen" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/gandalf" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/gollum" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn24"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/gollumen" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--  Ligne 3 -->
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn31"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/pasdebraspasdechocolat" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn32"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/sparta" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn33"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/sabre" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn34"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/darkvador" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!--  Ligne 4 -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn41"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn42"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/fightclub" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn43"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/forrestgump" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn44"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/darkvadorpereen" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!--  Ligne 5 -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn51"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/loki" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn52"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/dinercon1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn53"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/gollum" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn54"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/gollum" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>  
    <!--  Ligne 6 -->
    <!--  
        <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOnglet1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E2F2FF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn61"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/dinercondroit4" />

       <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn62"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
             android:src="@drawable/dinerconfemme5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn63"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/dinerconchampion6" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn64"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:layout_height="110px"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@drawable/dinerconsonne7" />
    </LinearLayout>
    -->
```

And onglet2.xml equal tab2.xml which is not really important right now ...